# Static page html loading

Tags: html, facebook, loading

Can I know the name of below, attach an image [image]

This Screen Shot taken from Facebook (While scrolling the timeline)

Thanks in advance :) #Iam Waiting

Comment: A placeholder maybe?

Comment: How did you do? Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different names for what you might search for:

- Placeholder
- Busy indicator
- Progress indicator
- Loading indicator

these represent a selection of commonly used terms for things like the one you presented. I am sure there are more that can be added.